# batch apex with json response

Tags: apex, visualforce, batch

Json response i got from facebook API. Used wrapper class to deserialize.

```
{
"accounts" : {
    "data" : [{
            "picture" : {
                "data" : {
                    "is_silhouette" : true,
                    "url" : "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c15.0.50.50/p50x50/405770_10150000700901972_765915345_n.png?oh=b9dfdfgg40ebc96d0992e27255ccc5a16d678&oe=58F973E1"
                }
            },
            "id" : "746973423232342126509",
            "name" : "Sneakpick"
    } 
    ],
    "paging" : {
        "cursors" : {
            "before" : "NzQ2OTczNfdgfDQyMTI2NTA5",
            "after" : "MTYxNjM2NdfgfzE3ODY1ODk5MQZDZD"
        }
    }
},
"id" : "115020323171435432395"
}
```

Wrapper class created using https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/

```
global class facebookpages {
global facebookpages()
{
} 
 global Accounts accounts {get;set;} 
global String id {get;set;}    
// inner class level 1 accounts 
global class Accounts {
    global List<Data_Z> data {get;set;} 
    global Paging paging {get;set;}

    global Accounts(JSONParser parser) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                String text = parser.getText();
                if (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                    if (text == 'data') {
                        data = new List<Data_Z>();
                        while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
                            data.add(new Data_Z(parser));
                        }
                    } else if (text == 'paging') {
                        paging = new Paging(parser);
                    } else {
                        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Accounts consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                        consumeObject(parser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
// inner class level 1 paging
global class Paging {
    global Cursors cursors {get;set;} 

    global Paging(JSONParser parser) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                String text = parser.getText();
                if (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                    if (text == 'cursors') {
                        cursors = new Cursors(parser);
                    } else {
                        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Paging consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                        consumeObject(parser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
 //    inner class  level 2 Cursors 
global class Cursors {
    global String before {get;set;} 
    global String after {get;set;} 

    global Cursors(JSONParser parser) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                String text = parser.getText();
                if (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                    if (text == 'before') {
                        before = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'after') {
                        after = parser.getText();
                    } else {
                        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Cursors consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                        consumeObject(parser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
// inner classes level 2 Data_Z 
global class Data_Z {
    global Picture picture {get;set;} 
    global String name {get;set;} 
    global String id {get;set;} 

    global Data_Z(JSONParser parser) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                String text = parser.getText();
                if (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                    if (text == 'picture') {
                        picture = new Picture(parser);
                    } else if (text == 'name') {
                        name = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'id') {
                        id = parser.getText();
                    } else {
                        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Data_Z consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                        consumeObject(parser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}     
 // innner class level 3 picture     
global class Picture {
    global Data data {get;set;} 

    global Picture(JSONParser parser) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                String text = parser.getText();
                if (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                    if (text == 'data') {
                        data = new Data(parser);
                    } else {
                        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Picture consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                        consumeObject(parser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
// inner class level 4 data 
global class Data {
    global Boolean is_silhouette {get;set;} 
    global String url {get;set;} 

    global Data(JSONParser parser) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                String text = parser.getText();
                if (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                    if (text == 'is_silhouette') {
                        is_silhouette = parser.getBooleanValue();
                    } else if (text == 'url') {
                        url = parser.getText();
                    } else {
                        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Data consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                        consumeObject(parser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

 // level 0 main class methods and properties 
global static void consumeObject(JSONParser parser) {
    Integer depth = 0;
    do {
        JSONToken curr = parser.getCurrentToken();
        if (curr == JSONToken.START_OBJECT || 
            curr == JSONToken.START_ARRAY) {
            depth++;
        } else if (curr == JSONToken.END_OBJECT ||
            curr == JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
            depth--;
        }
    } while (depth > 0 && parser.nextToken() != null);
}

global facebookpages(JSONParser parser) {
    while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
        if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
            String text = parser.getText();
            if (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                if (text == 'accounts') {
                    accounts = new Accounts(parser);
                } else if (text == 'id') {
                    id = parser.getText();
                } else {
                    System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Root consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                    consumeObject(parser);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
global static facebookpages parse(String json) {
    return new facebookpages(System.JSON.createParser(json));
}
}
```

Debug log after this i am getting data in this class object that is perfect.

```
|DEBUG|facebookpages:[accounts=Accounts:[data=(Data_Z:[id=74‌​6973509, name=Sneakpick, picture=Picture:[data=Data:[is_silhouette=true, url=scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c15.0.50.50/p50x50/…, Data_Z:[id=1616367158991, name=Busyday, picture=Picture:[data=Data:[is_silhouette=true, url=scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c15.0.50.50/p50x50/…), paging=Paging:[cursors=Cursors:[after=MTYxNjM2NzE3Y1ODMQZDZD‌​, before=NzQ2OTczNDTI2A5]]], id=11470363662]
```

I want to insert these pages names and ID using batch apex. tried as below. **stucked in Start method** **what to return and is there require to fire query ?**.

```
global class addfbpagestosystem implements Database.Batchable<sObject> 
{

 global final list<facebookpages.Data_Z> fbpages;
 global final String id;
 global addfbpagestosystem(list<facebookpages.Data_Z> fbpages,String id) 
 {
    this.id =id;
    this.fbpages=fbpages;
 }   
 global Iterable<sObject> start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{ // stucked in this method.
 /* MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c objfbpage = new MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c()
  return MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c;*/
}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<sObject> scope)
{    
   list<MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c> objmtfbpage = new list<MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c>();
   for(facebookpages.Data_Z objfbpage :fbpages)
   {
       MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c objrecfbpage = new MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c();
       objrecfbpage.MBT_SFFB__Facebook_ID__c=id;
       objrecfbpage.MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page_ID__c=objfbpage.id;
       objrecfbpage.MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page_Name__c=objfbpage.name;
       objrecfbpage.MBT_SFFB__Image__c=objfbpage.picture.data.url;           
       objrecfbpage.MBT_SFFB__Facebook_User_Relates_To_Page__c='a0H2800000B6nR0';
       objmtfbpage.add(objrecfbpage);
   }
    insert objmtfbpage;

}
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{
}
}
```

Comment: I don't really see why you need a batch Apex class at all just to insert what appears to be a handful of records. What are you trying to do?

Comment: There are No of facebook pagesnames and facebook pages post i need to insert into Salesforce object. for that i want to use batch apex. Page may contain No of posts.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting confused with the working of the batch.
Batch works via querying the records in the database in start Method and iterating it in execute. What I can see is you are not querying anything in start and hence your Batch wont work.

You can read here.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm

Comment: Do i need to fire query for the object in which i am inserting ? Here i am confused Please clarify.

Comment: You cannot querry something that you have not inserted.
As you are not querying anything I doubt if you really need a batch in the first place.  Let me give you a use case for batch. For every Account in SF you need to make a callout ont fb fetch data and save into database.

Comment: Right now batch is working but not inserting anything..

Comment: How are you executing batch? Provide syntax

Comment: Pranay, if you examine the batchable documentation more carefully, you will see that any `Iterable` can be returned from the start method; its most common for the Iterable (or QueryLocator) to be for an SObject but that is not required and sometimes it makes sense to return something else.

Comment: addfbpagestosystem c = new  addfbpagestosystem(objallfacebookpageslist,objallfacebookpages.id);
                Database.executeBatch(c);

Comment: Constructor is called perfectly But Start method is not called.